# Why are my IBOutlet-connected vars not instantiated when I create an instance?

Tags: swift, xcode, instantiation, iboutlet

I set some global variables equal to parameters of a class after it's instantiation. The class is defined as so:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class LogIn : UIViewController{

    var test:Int = 1

    @IBOutlet var login_icon: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet var username_field: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var password_field: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var login_button: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var createaccount_button: UIButton! 

}
```

The global variables are instantiated as so (within a viewDidAppear method):

```
func showLoginView(){
    self.startup_animation.image = self.seq_6
    let login_view = LogIn()
    self.login_icon = login_view.login_icon.image //Doesnt work
    self.username_field = login_view.username_field //Doesnt work
    self.password_field = login_view.password_field //Doesnt work
    self.login_button = login_view.login_button //Doesnt work
    self.createaccount_button = login_view.createaccount_button  //Doesnt work
    self.int_testval = login_view.test //Works  
}
```

All IBOutlets-connected variables after instantiation are nil values, but var test is instantiated fine. Why is this?

Thanks!

**Additional Context**
The showLoginView function is called with the viewDidAppear function. The whole class looks like so:

```
class StartupViewController: UIViewController {

var images: [UIImage]!

var animatedImage: UIImage!

@IBOutlet var startup_animation: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var startup_text: UIImageView!

var login_icon: UIImage!
var username_field: UITextField!
var password_field: UITextField!
var login_button: UIButton!
var createaccount_button: UIButton!


var seq_1 : UIImage!
var seq_2 : UIImage!
var seq_3 : UIImage!
var seq_4 : UIImage!
var seq_5 : UIImage!
var seq_6 : UIImage!
var seq_7 : UIImage!
var seq_8 : UIImage!

var rec_1 : UIImage!
var rec_2 : UIImage!
var rec_3 : UIImage!
var rec_4 : UIImage!
var rec_5 : UIImage!
var rec_6 : UIImage!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    seq_1 = UIImage(named: "Eceipt_seq1")
    seq_2 = UIImage(named: "Eceipt_seq2")
    seq_3 = UIImage(named: "Eceipt_seq3")
    seq_4 = UIImage(named: "Eceipt_seq4")
    seq_5 = UIImage(named: "Eceipt_seq5")
    seq_6 = UIImage(named: "Eceipt_seq6")
    seq_7 = UIImage(named: "Eceipt_seq7")
    seq_8 = UIImage(named: "Eceipt_seq8")

    images = [seq_1 ,seq_2, seq_3, seq_4, seq_5, seq_6, seq_7, seq_8]

    animatedImage = UIImage.animatedImage(with: images, duration: 0.8)

    startup_animation.image = animatedImage

    let transition_text = UIImage(named: "Eceipt_logo")

    UIView.transition(with: self.startup_text, duration: 3.0, options: .transitionCrossDissolve,
                      animations: {
                        self.startup_text.image = transition_text
    },
                      completion: { (finished: Bool) -> () in
                        self.showLoginView()
    })

}

func showLoginView(){
    self.startup_animation.image = self.seq_6
    let login_view = LogIn()
    self.login_icon = login_view.login_icon.image
    self.username_field = login_view.username_field
    self.password_field = login_view.password_field
    self.login_button = login_view.login_button
    self.createaccount_button = login_view.createaccount_button
}
```

Comment: That's because you did not mention xib or storyboard to load controller from, so your IBoutlets did not instantiated

Comment: Ah thanks - So even though I ctrl + dragged the views from storyboard to the LogIn class, I also need to specify the storyboard (ViewController) they're coming from? Would I go about doing that in the view did appear code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding the use of `@IBOutlet`.

`@IBOutlet` just means that it is an outlet of a view or some other object in the xib or storyboard file.

Your views are `nil` not because they are outlets, but because they are implicitly unwrapped optionals, which is `nil` if you don't give it a value.

`test` is not nil, because 1) it is not an optional type and 2) it has a value of `1`.

I suggest you put the `@IBOutlet`s in a `UIViewController` or `UIView` subclass and connect the appropriate views from the storyboard/xib file to it. This way, they will be initialised by the time the `viewDidLoad` method or `awakeFromNib` method is called.

EDIT:

It seems like that you already control+dragged the views to the `LogIn` class. In that case, check if the circles to the left of the outlets are filled. If they are, that means they are properly connected. You just need to wait until `awakeFromNib` gets called. If they are not, try connecting them again. Alternatively, just connect all your outlets directly to the view controller, which saves you lots of trouble.

EDIT 2:

Now that I understand what you are trying to do, here is what you should do. You just seems to want to present the `LogIn` VC. So instead of assigning every view to `self`, properly present it with the `present` method.

```
let vc = UIStoryboard.main!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Login")
present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Remember to give your login VC in the storyboard a Storyboard ID of "Login".

Comment: Hey thanks for the explanation, I think I am likely misunderstanding a few swift things as I jump in :). But in this case, the LogIn class subclasses ```UIViewController``` (I just edited the question code to reflect that), and all the IBOutlets are connected to image/button/textfield views in storyboard.

Comment: @AriK Is the second code snnipet in the same view controller as well? Can you show some context of the second snippet?

Comment: Yes it's in the same view controller. And I added full context at the bottom of the question. Thank you!                                                     **edit:** Sorry, I misunderstood your question, the second snippet is in a different view controller than LogIn. (Which is why I thought to approach taking LogIn views by instantiating an instance of it)

Comment: Thank you! Sorry for the roundabout explanation of my problem, this is indeed the answer I needed. -Ari

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you're instantiating the `LogIn` view controller by doing `let login_view = LogIn()`. When you instantiate a view controller with its empty initializer, every `IBOutlet` will be nil because the view controller is not "taken" from a storyboard (or a xib). If you want to use iboutles you must instantiate the view controller from a storyboard or from a xib; in your case (with the storyboard), you should instantiate it by doing:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil) // name is the filename of the storyboard that contains the vc
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LogIn") as! LogIn // you can cast to have the exact view controller type
present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Make sure that the view controller in your storyboard has the identifier "LogIn".

Comment: Thanks! Wish I could check mark multiple answers as correct. -Ari